# PYTHON 3X - p.stdin.write() equivalent in python3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Python3x equivalent for subprocess --> `p.stdin.write()` to give multiple interactive input to the jar file

Have tried using `p.stdin.write((string).encode(utf-8))` but it didnt help.

Below Code works but need to give all the inputs at same time which i am not looking for, Want to give input line by line:

```
line =  p.communicate(input=(text_String).encode())[0]
```

Comment: You don't write to `stdin`. `stdin` is for reading. `stdout` is for writing. Also what "jar file" are you referring to? Python doesn't use jar files.

Comment: I am running a jar file with subprocess.Popen which takes input in interactive form

Comment: OK, that is not really relevant and you had not mentioned it before you referred to it as "the jar file". Saying "the jar file" implies that you have already referred to a particular jar file before that. Anyway, did you try using `stdout` instead of `stdin`?

Comment: `>>> p.stdout.write('test\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
io.UnsupportedOperation: write`

Comment: Please edit your question to give a complete example. The error in your last comment does not make sense. There is no mention of `stdin` in the code mentioned in your comment, so why is the error referring to `stdin`? Please see also [mcve] and [ask].